# Optimization of DB2 query which uses joins and takes 1.5 hours to execute

Tags: sql, db2

when i run SELECT stataement on my view it takes around 1.5 hours to run, what can i do to optimize it.
Below is the sample structure of how my view looks like

```
 CREATE VIEW SCHEMANAME.VIEWNAME
    {
    COL, COL1, COL2, COL3 }
    AS SELECT
    COST.ETA,
    CASE
    WHEN VOL.CURR IS NOT NULL
THEN COALESCE {VOL.COMM,0}
END CASE,
CASE
WHEN...
END CASE
FROM TABLE1 t1 inner join TABLE2 t2 ON t1.ETA=t2.ETA
INNER JOIN TABLE3 t3 on t2.ETA=t3.ETA
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE4 t4 on t2.ETA=t4.ETA
```

Comment: Impossible to answer without much more info.

Comment: what more info should i add ?

Comment: Table definitions, incl indexes, constraints etc. Data amount, distribution etc. What's in the "when..."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT COST.ETA,
       (CASE WHEN VOL.CURR IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE {VOL.COMM,0}
        END) as ??,
        . . .
FROM TABLE1 t1 inner join
     TABLE2 t2
     ON t1.ETA = t2.ETA INNER JOIN
     TABLE3 t3
     on t2.ETA = t3.ETA LEFT OUTER JOIN
     TABLE4 t4
     on t2.ETA = t4.ETA;
```

First, I will the fact that the `select` clause references tables that are not in the `from` clause.  I assume this is a typo.

Second, you should be able to use indexes to improve this query:  `table1(eta)`, `table2(eta),`table3(eta)`, and`table4(eta).

Third, I am highly suspicious on seeing the same column used for joining so many tables.  I suspect that you might have cartesian products occurring, because there are multiple values of any given `eta` in several tables.  If that is the case, you need to fix the query to better reflect what you really need.  If so, ask another question with sample data and desired results, because your query is probably not correct.